# Inject html into iframe with document.domain

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I go about circumventing the same-origin policy with document.domain?

I'm trying to inject html and css into my iframe from a different domain, but this isn't allowed.
How do I amend this?

The code I have so far is here:

https://pastebin.com/SCpCzDqP

```js
function updateIframe() {
  document.domain = "domain.com";
  var myFrame = $("#myframe").contents().find('body');
  var textareaValue = "<h1>test2</h1>";
  myFrame.html(textareaValue);
}
```

```css
textarea,
iframe {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<body onload="updateIframe()">
  <iframe width="100%" height="1000" id="myframe" src="https://stevebeyerproductions.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

The domain I want to change the elements within is: https://stevebeyerproductions.com (I'm working for this company, not trying to steal their content btw.)

I do apologies if I'm asking the wrong things in the wrong places, this is my first post.

Comment: Just realized my text is written incorrectly, sorry

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Please do not try to circumvent the rejections when you do not post code

Comment: You can't do that: if that's possible it represents a severe security flaw. This means that any website (malicious or not) and embed a third party site and manipulate its contents.

Comment: Answer is: You do not. You can use a server side proxy or a bookmarklet but otherwise you will fail in the attempt to hack an obvious security issue